# Spotfire- limiting Information link colum expression

Tags: spotfire

I have a column of data [Sales ID] that bringing in duplicate data for an analysis. My goal is to try and limit the data to pull unique sales ID's for the max day of every month in the analysis only (instead of daily). Im basically trying to get it to only pull in unique sales ID values for the last the day of every month in the analysis ,and if the current day is the last day so far then it should pull that in. So it should pull in the MAX date in any given month. Please how do i write an expresion with the [Sales ID] column and [Date ] column to acieve this?

Comment: the wording of your question ("limit the data to pull unique sales ID's for the max day of every month in the analysis only") suggests you need to do this on the data side of things, in which case, please share your SQL from the Information Designer. if that's not the case (ie, you're okay with having data from previous dates in the analysis, but maybe not on a specific visualization), please indicate and share what you've tried to do so far.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We are basically trying to do it on the data in demand to limit data that's throwing off a bar chart data. At the moment that data is pulling all the sales ID's into the dash board and when we aggregate it it not correct. This is the  Expression i tried on the bar chart but it didn't work: [sales ID]=Max([sales ID])over ([Month],[Year]). i would be grateful if you could tell me how to do it on the Data on demand. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably the two easiest options are to

1) Adjust the SQL as niko mentioned

2) Limit the visualization with the "Limit Data Using Expression" option, using the following:

```
Rank(Day([DATE]), "desc", Month([DATE]), Year([DATE])) = 1
```

If you had to do it in the Data on Demand section (maybe the IL itself is a usp or you don't have permission to edit it), my preference would be to create another data table that only has the max dates for each month, and then filter your first data table by that.

However, if you really need to do it in the Data on Demand section, then I'm guessing you don't have the ability to create your own information links.  This would mean you can't key off additional data tables, and you're probably going to have to get creative.

Constraints of creativity include needing to know the "rules" of your data -- are you pulling the data in daily?  Once a week?  Do you have today's data, or today - 2?  You could *probably* write a python script to grab the last day of every month for the last 10 years, and then whatever yesterday's date was, and throw all those values into a document property.  This would allow you to do a "Values from Property".

(Side Note: I want to say you could also do it directly in the expression portion with something like an extremely long
`Date(DateTimeNow()),DateAdd("dd",-1,Date(Year(DateTimeNow()), Month(DateTimeNow()), 1))`

But Spotfire is refusing to accept that as multiple values.  Interestingly, when I pull the logic for a StringList property, it gives this: $map("${udDates}", ","), which suggests commas are an accurate methodology, but I get an error reading "Expected 'End of expression' but found ','" .  Uncertain if this is a Spotfire issue, or related to my database connection)

**tl;dr** -- Doing it in the Data on Demand section is probably convoluted.  Recommend adjusting in SQL if possible, and otherwise limiting in the visualization